# In Powershell, how do I set an environment variable by supplying the name as a $var?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

Typically, in PowerShell you would use

```
env:VARIABLE = "Some kind of value"
```

But my issue is that I have the name of the variable in a string object.  PowerShell does not recognize it as a string object and uses the variable name as the name of the environment variable.

For example, if I do this:

```
$someVariable = "MY_ENV_VAR"
env:$someVariable = "Some kind of value"
```

The result is `$someVariable` being literally defined as an environment variable instead of `MY_ENV_VAR`.  I've tried numerous iterations of using `${}` as if there were periods in the string, but nothing I have found works.

How can I use PowerShell's `Env:` using a string object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "Env" drive is a provider so you can use the *-Item cmdlets on it e.g.:

```
New-Item env:$someVariable -Value "some kind of value"
```

Comment: You may wish to add " -Force | Out-Null" to overwrite existing values and do not print to console.

Comment: Don't need for `-Force`, just use `Set-Item` instead of `New-Item`